# Reading of 上 in the sentence:じょう or うえ

Tags: readings, parsing, suffixes

I was reading the [news](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20200531/k10012452431000.html) when I saw the sentence with 上で (see the sentence with highlight).

[image]

I was thinking if it should be read as うえ or じょう。I am inclined to read this as じょう because it doesn't fit into the expression うえで which shows that something happens *after* one thing, but at the same time, I am not 100% sure because I haven't seen じょう (which probably means "being of the type of" based on rikaikun add-on) in this context before.

Sure, I have seen じょう in contexts presented in [here](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%98%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-jou/) where it means "for the sake of, from the standpoint of" but I don't think the sentence in question falls under this category of じょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are of course correct to consider the various more grammatical usages of 上, but in this case, its meaning happens to have a fairly direct correspondence to one of its simpler/normal translations into English, of "on".

インターネット上（で） is an expression, where 「上」 is read 「じょう」, meaning "**on** the Internet". I have less commonly heard an equivalent expression インターネット**の**上（で） where the 「上」 read 「うえ」.

The relevant clause in the text「急きょ制作した動画をインターネット上で公開し」therefore simply says that they made the rapidly-produced video available on the internet.

Comment: oh, of course. I have not considered translating it to "on." I was thinking that the インターネット上 translates to something like "online version" but after reading your answer, I realized how wrong I was to think that way considering that author would have chosen "オンライン版" if he wanted to mean "online version"