# What is the meaning and pronunciation of 上 in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, pronunciation, suffixes

「新聞・雑誌などの編集上の一区分。」

This sentence came from one of the definitions for the word 「欄（らん）」 in the "Super Daijirin" dictionary. I'm having trouble honing in on what specific meaning and pronunciation 「上」 could have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading of 上 in the sentence:じょう or うえ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77770/reading-of-%e4%b8%8a-in-the-sentence%e3%81%98%e3%82%87%e3%81%86-or-%e3%81%86%e3%81%88)

Answer (score 2):

～上【じょう】 is a nominal suffix that has many ways of translation, but here it is used in the sense "in the scope/discussion of —". English does not have a word that consistently matches it, but I hope you can get it from my examples.

> 編集上のミス *an editorial* (= during the editing work) *error*
> 編集的なミス *an editorial* (= typically editors-like) *error*
>
> 感覚上の反応 *a sensory* (= of sensory organ) *response*
> 感覚的な反応 *an intuitive* (= driven by sensation) *response*
>
> 歴史上の事件 *a historical* (= told in the history) *event*
> 歴史的な事件 *a historic* (= important in the history) *event*